# ElementNotVisibleException in Selenium for a calender date input

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to input sendKeys to a calendar date element in FireFox browser using Selenium. The element is displayed but I keep getting below exception:

```
Caused by: **org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with**
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
System info: host: 'abcde-693bdc76f', ip: '192.168.1.4', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

The locator uniquely identifies the element; there was only one element in the list when I executed findElements.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[id='depart_date']")));
WebElement startDate = (WebElement)   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='depart_date']"));
startDate.isDisplayed();
startDate.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
startDate.sendKeys("20/09/2015");
```

Below is the HTML code for the element:

```
<div id="travel_dates-start-wrapper" class="r9-datepicker-wrapper r9-  datepicker-twofields r9-datepicker-start-empty">
    <span class="r9-datepicker-icon r9-icon-calendar-depart"></span>
    <span id="travel_dates-start" class="r9-datepicker-section r9-datepicker-start">
        <span id="travel_dates-start-display" class="r9-datepicker-display" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0" aria-label="Start Date"></span>
        <span id="travel_dates-start-placeholder" class="r9-datepicker-placeholder">Depart</span>
    </span>
    <span id="travel_dates-start-clear" class="r9-datepicker-clear"></span>
    <input id="travel_dates-start-tab" class="r9-datepicker-tab" type="text" readonly="true">
    <input id="depart_date" class="r9-datepicker-input r9-datepicker-start" type="text" value="" name="depart_date">
</div>
```

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so sorry if there is anything wrong with my post. I found quite a few questions on the same exception. Tried everything but nothing seems to work and I am stuck with what seems like a simple problem. Please help.

Edit: Changed from `span` to `input` on @spcial's suggestion below.
      Still doesn't work.

Comment: You did good for your first post. You did your own research, tried some things, and posted relevant info so that we can better help you. The only thing I would recommend is when you post HTML, use a beautifier like jsbeautifier.org to format the HTML. It indents it, etc. for you so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... do over now that I have the actual site. This code is working. It sets the start and end airports and the start and end dates of the flight.

NOTE: You are NOT allowed to scrape the KAYAK site for ANYTHING other than personal use. See their [terms of use](http://www.kayak.com/actual-terms-of-use/)

> In addition, you agree not to do any of the following without prior
>   express written permission of KAYAK:
>
> (i) access the Good Stuff with any manual or automated process for any
>   purpose other than your personal use or for inclusion of KAYAK pages
>   in a search index;

```
driver.get("http://www.kayak.com/flights");
WebElement originFlight = driver.findElement(By.id("origin"));
originFlight.clear(); // clear the default airport
originFlight.sendKeys("JFK");
driver.findElement(By.id("destination")).sendKeys("LAX");
driver.findElement(By.id("travel_dates-start")).click();
WebElement startDate = driver.findElement(By.id("travel_dates-start-display"));
startDate.clear(); // clear the default start date
startDate.sendKeys("12/1/2015");
driver.findElement(By.id("travel_dates-end")).click();
WebElement endDate = driver.findElement(By.id("travel_dates-end-display"));
endDate.clear(); // clear the default end date
endDate.sendKeys("12/15/2015");
```

The problem was that you had to click the start/end date control to get the element to appear so you could type in the dates.

Comment: I had tried the By.id before moving on to css selector. User can either type the date or use the datepicker. I assumed it would be easy for me to just type in the dates. Anyway, if it helps,  the website I was trying this on is kayak.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had even tried clicking on the fields before inputting, but I had used the same ids for clicking and inputting on the fields. So it did not recognise.

Comment: If this, or any, answer helped you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to send keys to a HTML `span` element which is not a `input` field? I don't know how the HTML code looks like in action but I would try to send the keys to the regarding `depart_date` `input` element e.g.:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[id='depart_date']")));
WebElement startDate = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='depart_date']"));
```

Comment: I had tried your suggestion before using By.id(). But it didn't work. Either way, I agree span doesn't make sense. So changed code above to use input with cssSelector. But still the same exception. :(

Comment: Hmm.. you could try to change your `wait.until` expected condition to: `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id='depart_date']"))`

Comment: Even this doesn't work. The isDisplayed for span (calendar) returns true but returns false for date input field. Thanks for your comments though. I can't think of anything else other than trying with another version.

Comment: The cast to `WebElement` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you check

```
startDate.isDisplayed();
```

is the answer true or false (element visible or not)? If not clearly you cannot interact with it.
However, it happened to me that Selenium reported an element to be not visible but because a bug in their `isDiplayed()` method. In this case try another version of the browser (older or newer) and another version of the driver (older or newer)

Comment: isDisplayed() returns false. I will try with another version of the browser. Thanks.